# How to take off Discord Roles within minutes of NFT holders when they sold or transfer their nfts?

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metaplex-js, api, discord

We are building a Discord holder verification tool on solana and we are almost done with 80% work

We are using metaplex SDK to find nfts in the wallet of users.

But we have one query how to have a watch on wallet activity ?

How to know if one user has sold his nft and how will it triggers in discord that the role is removed ?

We know how to remove role in discord but we don't know how to remove users role within minutes if nft owner gets changed.

We have an route that does all the conditions check for all the user ?

But how is that possible to hit that route every 5 seconds for 1000 of users ?

Answer (score 2):

You have different options to track and verify wallets.

E.g. you can either watch marketplace addresses, or ALL the wallets which contain your NFTs. If you actually want to do see those sales in seconds it might be worth to listen to account changes with the [solana web3 js package](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange)

The metaplex JS SDK also includes this function and you can use it with

```
    metaplex.connection.onAccountChange(metaplex.identity().publicKey,
      () => checkUserNFTs()
    );
```

This will trigger function checkUserNFTs as soon as a wallet changes.

Depending on the amount of users / wallets that you have to track opening that many websockets is not really an option though.

Maybe it could make more sense to leverage the [helius labs API](https://docs.helius.xyz/api-reference/nft-api/nft-events) to listen for events.